# Are there immutable objects besides Strings in Java?

Tags: java, c++, string, object, immutability

I only heard that strings in Java cannot be immutable and I was wondering are there other objects besides strings that are also immutable?

On a side note, are strings in C++ immutable too?

Comment: Yes, there are many immutable objects in Java. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to find some, and to *create some*. And no, C++ Strings are not immutable. They're simply arrays of char.

Comment: Hi Hovercraft. Wow I'm surprised there are other immutable objects out there. Okay I will find some or create some as a learning exercise.

Comment: There's nothing to be surprised about. There's a very good reason why there are so many of these, and what you really should do is to find out *why* immutable objects are so attractive, what exactly their benefits are.

Comment: I did find out one reason: security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the primitive types are immutable (Integer, Long, Boolean, etc). Immutability is not something that is explicitly noted in java, it's really a semantic contract. You can make any class immutable by declaring it's members as final, assigning them on construction, and locking down access through a class's public interface.

A String in C++ is a character array ending in a zero character. That's it. This has no promises of immutability, though use of const can help lock down access.

I guess the point is that many things in Java are immutable, but only the documentation and source can really prove this to you.

Comment: "string" is a concept in C++, with many implementations.  A null terminated string is a character array ending in a zero character.  There's also `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `CString`, `_bstr_t`, `QString`, 5 kinds of string literals, `string_ref`...

Comment: Point taken, my C++ knowledge is holdover from my university days.

Comment: But you can change the values of primitives if you assign it a new value, no? I don't see how primitives are immutable.

Comment: @user983246 That does not change the value of the primitive. These are reference types, so if you have Integer a = Integer.valueOf(1); then later, a = Integer.valueOf(2) - a now refers to a different, immutable, instance of the Integer class. As a better example, say you called someInstance.setFoo(a); then a = Integer.valueOf(10); - someInstance will still have the original value of 'a', not 10. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Oh there are two different objects then!

Answer (score 1):

All of the boxed primitives, for example Integer, are immutable.

You can make immutable classes yourself - for example, a class that sets its variables using its constructor, and has no public variables or setters.

Comment: what do you mean by boxed?

Comment: @user983246, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html